# Sage cell installation not working, extreme frustration

Tags: bash, terminal, cell, sage

I have spent all day trying to install the Sage Cell package and have been quite frustrated. I have been following the instructions at:https://github.com/sagemath/sagecell

Seems pretty reasonable, huh?

First problem occurred at step 4, in the "UPDATE:" that requires a git pull. After attempting the git-pull many times, and googling the error I was getting, which was: `fatal: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/4195/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?`

It seemed to be that either the pull had been deleted or I somehow didn't have permissions to get it. However, the instructions on the site: http://sage.math.washington.edu/home/jason/sagecell/README.html don't have the UPDATE so I figured I'd go ahead and attempt the install anyways. I ran `./sage -i http://sage.math.washington.edu/home/jason/sagecell-spkg/sagecell-2014-03-01.spkg` and got a long, winded error which looks something like this:

```
Note: Bypassing https://pypi.python.org/simple/backports.ssl_match_hostname/ (disallowed host; see http://bit.ly/1dg9ijs for details).


Note: Bypassing https://pypi.python.org/simple/backports.ssl-match-hostname/ (disallowed host; see http://bit.ly/1dg9ijs for details).

Couldn't find index page for 'backports.ssl_match_hostname' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)

Note: Bypassing https://pypi.python.org/simple/ (disallowed host; see http://bit.ly/1dg9ijs for details).

No local packages or download links found for backports.ssl-match-hostname
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('backports.ssl-match-hostname')
Error installing tornado-3.2.tar.gz.

real    0m8.891s
user    0m2.315s
sys 0m0.933s
************************************************************************
Error installing package sagecell-2014-03-01
```

Followed by contact info for sage, who I have also emailed but am hoping for a response here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer all this, but I am pretty sure that Sage currently has Ipython 1.2 or so, and Sage 6.3 will have Ipython 2.1 or so.  My suspicion is hence that those steps are more than unnecessary.

Edit: However, this doesn't seem to be the cause of the backport error message...  See [this sage-devel thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sage-devel/kiSHd5ahiMQ/eDLYdKEFNTwJ):

> I had  to do
>
> ./sage -sh -c "easy_install backports.ssl-match-hostname"
>
> before installing the package - this way this thing is downloaded and
>   installed, while during installation of the package extra downloads
>   are prohibited.

Comment: Oh, was that the problem?  This is all based on informed guesswork...  I've also submitted a pull request to update the instructions.  I would not be at all surprised if the patches in https://github.com/sagemath/sagecell/blob/master/sage-patches/ needed some updating as well, don't lose heart though!

Comment: Also, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sage-support/nxy_BFvEtPw/sCGkSNjfctAJ may be useful - but be warned, it's from a different (non-spkg-based) workflow.

Answer (score 1):

The Sage Cell installation instructions are in a state of flux as we transfer maintainership over to Andrey Novoseltsev.  Before that, the best way to understand how to install the cell server was to use/mimic the shell scripts I used to install the public server (in the contrib/vm directory) because these shell scripts changed sometimes daily, and my focus was on pushing the main server forward.

Andrey is working on the install process now, and said (in response to hearing about this stackexchange post): "This is definitely my project for this week. I can't promise a particular date time since I have some other things going on, but I'll make sure that install of sagecell.sagemath.org is documented in the way it can be repeated and all others are either removed or marked clearly as not tested/working. Thank you for keeping track of things!"